# ionic 4 app shows white screen on ios with error code 1100

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I recently had to rename the ios app so ended up removing and re-adding the ios platform. but after that now the app runs on device and emulator with a blank screen. This comes after the splash screen is gone.

Looking into IOS logs in xcode it shows:

```
2019-04-30 17:17:40.679217-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2019-04-30 17:17:40.702973-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] Using UIWebView
2019-04-30 17:17:40.703804-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] [CDVTimer][handleopenurl] 0.056982ms
2019-04-30 17:17:40.705005-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] [CDVTimer][intentandnavigationfilter] 1.125097ms
2019-04-30 17:17:40.705113-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] [CDVTimer][gesturehandler] 0.032902ms
2019-04-30 17:17:40.705714-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] [CDVTimer][codepush] 0.519037ms
2019-04-30 17:17:40.719445-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] [CDVTimer][file] 13.651967ms
2019-04-30 17:17:40.719995-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] CDVIonicKeyboard: resize mode 1
2019-04-30 17:17:40.720810-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] CDVIonicKeyboard: WARNING!!: Keyboard plugin works better with WK
2019-04-30 17:17:40.720932-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 1.355052ms
2019-04-30 17:17:40.727548-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] [CDVTimer][splashscreen] 6.543994ms
2019-04-30 17:17:40.729983-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] [CDVTimer][statusbar] 2.328992ms
2019-04-30 17:17:40.730089-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 26.588917ms
2019-04-30 17:17:41.116994-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2019-04-30 17:17:41.396462-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197907] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2019-04-30 17:17:41.403209-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197909] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2019-04-30 17:17:41.404099-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197919] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2019-04-30 17:17:41.405120-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197907] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2019-04-30 17:17:41.408130-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197907] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2019-04-30 17:17:41.409071-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197919] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2019-04-30 17:17:41.409799-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197907] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100
2019-04-30 17:17:41.415742-0700 Scan Buddy[31529:12197837] Finished load of: file:///Users/moblizeit/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E1549FDB-7183-4E27-A2E8-7C6B4D7ABF95/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ACB65389-8CF7-4887-8303-6E324B8E7E2A/Scan%20Buddy.app/www/index.html
```

I have looked into all the threads but none seems to have a solution.
Also, this works just fine on Android.

Comment: You are calling any API when application starts loading?

Comment: same problem happened to me lately. did you manage to fix the problem.

Comment: I can now replicate in a simulator. If you run your code in a simulator and look at the device log in xcode you should see a link to: file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/guid/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/guid/MyApp.app/www/index.html

Open this file in Chrome and in the network tab you  can see which requests are actually not resolving. In my case it can't pick up my Angular/Ionic scripts using the request URL: file:///main.js (for example). Don't have a fix yet, but this is a start

Comment: Managed to fix it although still don't know the cause. I started a fresh Ionic project then copied my stuff across and it fixed it. Best of luck.